# Build object with specific lifetime

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime

I have a problem that I don't know exactly how to model into Rust, in regard with ownership, lifetime and all that.

I have a large struct:

```
struct LargeStruct {
    x: f32,
    n: i32,
    // lot of other fields.
}
```

The struct being large, I want to avoid copies, and therefore I carry around pointers to it.

I have a `foo` function that takes a pointer to `LargeStruct` and a `f32` value. If this value is larger than the field `x`, I want to create a new object with `x` set to this value, and returns it. If it is not larger, then I want to return the original pointer itself.

I naively implemented it like this:

```
fn foo(object: &LargeStruct, y: f32) -> &LargeStruct {
    if object.x < y {
        LargeStruct {
            x: y,
            n: object.n,
            // ...
        }
    }
    else {
        object
    }
}
```

But it does not work: the two branches of the if do no return the same type. In the first case, I actually return a `LargeStruct`, and in the second I return a `&LargeStruct`. If I modify the object construction to take its pointer:

```
    &LargeStruct {
```

then it doesn't work either: the lifetime of the object constructed is too short, so I can not return that from the function.

If I try to build the object on the heap:

```
    ~LargeStruct {
```

I have now another compilation error:

> if and else have incompatible types: expected `~LargeStruct` but found
>   `&LargeStruct` (expected &-ptr but found ~-ptr)

I tried to specify a lifetime in the function signature:

```
fn foo<'a>(object: &'a LargeStruct, y: f32) -> &'a LargeStruct {
```

But it does not help: I don't know how to build a new `LargeStruct` with the same lifetime.

I am calling this function like this:

```
fn main() {
    let object = LargeStruct{ 
        x: 1.0, 
        n: 2,
        // ...
    };

    let result = foo(&object, 2.0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The intent behind your approach is to only return a modified copy under certain conditions if I understand it right. In Rust this can be modeled with a function that returns an `Option<~LargeStruct>` type (perhaps even with `Option<LargeStruct>` but I'm not sure if the compiler can efficiently move large objects in this case).

```
fn foo(object: &LargeStruct, y: f32) -> Option<~LargeStruct> {
    if object.x < y {
        return Some(~LargeStruct {
            x: y,
            //n: object.n,
            // ...
        })
    }
    None
}
```

As for why your approach didn't work: Rust doesn't let you return a reference to an object that will be freed once the function returns. A lifetime is a way to say that an object must live at least as long as the references to it.

Comment: OK, but with that approach you return `None` when the condition is not met, instead of the original reference like I was intending to. I would like it to be transparent to the calling site, so that it uses the result of the function without needing to know which branch was hit. Anyway, thanks for the explanation about the reference.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but I don't understand what a `~LargeStruct` is. I googled for this syntax, but found no result; I tried on the playground, both in stable and in nightly, but the compiler doesn't seem to understand. What does it mean? There is a hint in the OP question that this would allocate `LargeStruct` on the heap, but isn't that the role of `Box``?

Answer (score 3):

### The answer to the question as asked

It is not possible to design something in this way with it *completely* transparent; a reference must always have a lifetime not in excess of the scope of its owner; it is thus impossible to return a reference to an object whose scope does not exceed the function.

This can be solved in a way with an enum specifying the return type as either a reference to a LargeStruct or a LargeStruct, but it's clumsy:

```
pub struct LargeStruct {
    a: int,
}

pub enum LargeStructOrRef<'a> {
    LargeStructRef(&'a LargeStruct),
    LargeStruct(LargeStruct),
}

fn foo<'a>(object: &'a LargeStruct, y: f32) -> LargeStructOrRef<'a> {
    if object.x < y {
        LargeStruct(LargeStruct {
            x: y,
            n: object.n,
            // ...
        })
    } else {
        LargeStructRef(object)
    }
}
```

You'd then need to do pattern matching between `LargeStruct` and `LargeStructRef`—it can't be made transparent to the caller.

### Alternative designs

You can probably design this in a different way which will resolve these difficulties. For example, you might make `foo` take a `&mut LargeStruct` and modify the struct rather than creating a new one if `object.x < y`. (This is most likely to be the design you actually want, I think.)